# Java Stream Group By Row When It Fetched From Database

Tags: java, java-stream

Let's say I have these piece of code. As far as I know, the code below, runs like that if I have 10 query and run them at the same time, and each query return 10M results, I have to wait 100M rows fetched from Database to start group function.

My problem, since the cardinality of Country and City cartesian product is low, And the number of rows which I have to fetch from database is huge. I wanna immediately calcute the group result when a row fetched from database. How can I do that using Java Stream?

```
  myqueries
 .parallelstream()
 .map( m-> { 
    //queryresult is a stream which return database rows
    return queryresult;
 })
 .flatMap(fm-> fm)
 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(g-> {
                    List<Object> objects = Arrays.<Object>asList(
                    g.getCountry(),
                    g.getCity());
                    return objects;
                }, Collectors.toList()))


                .entrySet().stream().map(m-> {
                    MyResultClass item = new MyResultClass();
                    item.setCountry((String) m.getKey().get(0));
                    item.setCity((String) m.getKey().get(1));
                    item.setSumField1(m.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(m2-> m2.getSumField1()).sum());
                    item.setSumField2(m.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(m2-> m2.getSumField2()).sum());
                    item.setSumField3(m.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(m2-> m2.getSumField3()).sum());                 
                    return item;
                 }).forEach(f-> {

                //print the MyResultClass fields
        });
```

Comment: `.flatMap(fm-> fm)` is redundant.

Comment: `.flatMap(fm-> fm)` is not redundant here. But better way is, directly apply `flatMap` in the previous `map` so that  separate `map` and `flatMap` not required.

Comment: @Mrinal That's what I meant.

Comment: Right. I interpreted literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your solution is, you are collecting all data into a list, just to do further reduction. So it will accumulate all data into memory. You can combine both reduction into single one using [toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) like this :

```
myqueries
 .parallelstream()
 .flatMap( m-> { 
    //queryresult is a stream which return database rows
    return queryresult;
 })
 .collect(Collectors.toMap(
               g-> Arrays.<Object>asList(g.getCountry(), g.getCity()),
               v -> { 
                      MyResultClass item = new MyResultClass();
                      item.setCountry(v.getCountry());
                      item.setCity(v.getCity());
                      return item;
                    },
                (t, u) -> {
                       t.setSumField1(t.getSumField1() + u.getSumField1());
                       t.setSumField2(t.getSumField2() + u.getSumField3());
                       t.setSumField3(t.getSumField3() + u.getSumField3());
                       return t;
                      }
                 )
                .values().forEach(f-> {

                //print the MyResultClass fields
                });
```

Also, note that, when you use parallelStream here, that does not mean all queries will be running in parallel. Parallelism will depend on number of queries, number of cores in your machine and runtime environment. If you want to  control the concurrent query behaviour, better use [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Another point to note is, execution will also depend on how you are creating Stream from the query result in the first place. If you wait till you get all result, and then create Stream, then you will defeat the purpose of the question itself.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I did it but i have little problem when i run parallel. i put sample code on github. Could you check it? https://github.com/ftylmz1/groupbytest

Comment: Replace `t.setMyCount(t.getMyCount() + 1);` with `t.setMyCount(t.getMyCount() + u.getMyCount());`.